# Opencv plane detection with AR marker

Tags: opencv, augmented-reality, aruco

Say I have an aruco on a table, how can I place an object (say image) on the table using the aruco to calculate the table plane. I don't want to place the object on the aruco, but rather on the same plane (like next to it, before it (closer to the viewer) etc).
Assume I know how to detect the aruco corners. It's the perspective transform to another table location I'm looking.

-- EDIT --

Adding sample image of what I am trying to achieve:
(please ignore my bad photoshop skills)

[image: aruco]

Now I know I can use opencv perspective transform between the business card to the aruco detected corners, but wouldn't that distort the b-card to be square? how can I calculate the "correct" destination coords of the b-card on the table? so I would use them in `getPerspectiveTransform` (and not the aruco corners).

Comment: QR codes are ill suited to this. you need some kind of real Augmented Reality marker. they differ from QR codes by a square outline. QR codes don't have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are trying to place a 3D object next to the aruco code, just place the object center like (0,1,0) in the world, aruco assume the marker center as world origin [aruco world origin](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html), and use the rt transfrom from pose estimated(solvepnp) as the world to camera transform in your 3D rendering setup like opengl, ogre or Unity3D. dont forget to adjust your camera with the calibrated parameters with the real camera you captuer image. that's not easy if you are not familiar with 3D rendering things, but I believe that you can find some code or even plugins for Unity3D.

if you are trying to place a 2D image, next to the aruco code, there is an easier, "not so 3D" way. with the 4 detected corner points in 2D origin image space, `cv::aruco::detectMarkers(image, dictionary, corners, ids);` you can get the perspective transform from the image you want to puts in, to origin source image with the marker, `Mat cv::getPerspectiveTransform (   InputArray  src, InputArray  dst, int     solveMethod = DECOMP_LU  )`   . then you can apply  this perspective transform to the image you wants to put in with `cv::warpPerspective (InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray M, Size dsize, int flags=INTER_LINEAR, int borderMode=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar &borderValue=Scalar())`. the overlay this to the original image.

if you want something like, next to the marker, just project points like (1,1,0) to the 2D image with rt transform from pose estimation. and replace the 4 2D points.

Comment: thx for you reply.

For simplicity, lets say I want to place a rectangle business card image next to the square aruco. isnt `getPerspectiveTransform` between the two change the aspect ratio of the business card (like turn it to square)?

Also, do you have some references (or examples) where I can learn what is "rt transform from pose estimation".

Thanks!

Comment: perspective transform is a transform from business card image space(says you have a business card 200*200, take the 4 corner points coordinate) to camera captured image space(aka your camera capture a 640*480 image, the aruco marker is detected and 4 corners coordinate). search some ref for 2D image transform.

Comment: for rt transform from pose estimation, <learn opencv> book holds a good chacter for augemented reality https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/tree/master/AugmentedRealityWithArucoMarkers

Comment: Added more info in the question to better explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: seeing the edited sample picture. it's just the last part of my answer "if you want something like, next to the marker, just project points like (1,1,0) to the 2D image with rt transform from pose estimation. and replace the 4 2D points." just make 4 corner 3D points in the same plane of the aruco corner planes. project them to 2D image, and getperspective transform